# Error page with strange code in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

When I've an error my page doesn't show stack trace, is showing strange codes instead.
[image: strange codes]

When I show my elmah.axd log the error is catched normally.

[image: elmah.axd log]

What's happening?